# How can I write the following in Jena?

Tags: rdf, jena

How can I write a Jena statement for the following:

```
:process1 sio:' is denoted by' : process effect_result
```

`' is denoted by'` is just a label, and `sio` is a namespace in http://semanticscience.org/resource/.

Comment: Anyone who knows that Jena is an RDF library, and knows anything about RDF, will find this perfectly legible.

Comment: Hamid - please note that your question was initially closed because it seemed too vague. I requested that the question got re-opened (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115608/re-open-closed-question), but please be aware of the feedback you're getting from the community and take care to ask questions as clearly as possible in the future. In particular, please take some time to read the markup guidelines for StackOverflow questions (see http://goo.gl/FuEr9), as your question was much clearer once other users had fixed the markup.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to define an ontology in which your properties are defined. This isn't *strictly* necessary, but it's definitely good practice. Ideally, your ontology should be available on the web at the namespace address you assign to it (`http://semanticscience.org/resource` in your case). Here's possible a fragment of the ontology, insofar as I understand what you are trying to model:

```
@prefix sio: <http://semanticscience.org/resource/>.
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

<> a owl:Ontology;
    rdfs:label "Process ontology";
    dc:author "hamid";
.

sio:denotedBy
    a owl:ObjectProperty;
    rdfs:domain sio:Process;
    rdfs:range sio:ProcessEffect;
    rdfs:label "is denoted by"@en;
.
```

In your Java code, you simply need to reference the URI's defined in your ontology. There are, broadly, two ways to do that:

- manually define constants in your code
- use Jena to automatically generate Java constants from your ontology file

The second approach uses Jena's [schemagen tool](http://jena.sourceforge.net/how-to/schemagen.html). I would actually recommend using this approach eventually, but to get started you may find it easier just to define the constants manually in your code. The main drawback from doing so is in program maintenance: if you change the ontology file in future, you need to remember to update your manually created constants, otherwise you'll find yourself trying to track down bugs that have suddenly appeared in your code.

Here's an example class that defines the constants manually, then defines `process1` with reference to `processEffect1`:

```
package test;


// Imports
///////////////

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;

public class ProcessTest
{
    @SuppressWarnings( value = "unused" )
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( ProcessTest.class );

    public static final String SIO = "http://semanticscience.org/resource/";
    public static final Resource Process = ResourceFactory.createResource( SIO + "Process" );
    public static final Resource ProcessEffect = ResourceFactory.createResource( SIO + "ProcessEffect" );
    public static final Property denotedBy = ResourceFactory.createProperty( SIO + "denotedBy" );

    public void run() {
        // create a model to hold the RDF statements we want to define
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );

        // inform m about the sio: prefix - not necessary, but makes the output prettier
        m.setNsPrefix( "sio", SIO );

        // create the individual for the process being defined
        Individual p1 = m.createIndividual( SIO + "process1", Process );

        // create the individual for the process effect
        Individual pe1 = m.createIndividual( SIO + "processEffect1", ProcessEffect );

        // the process is denoted by the effect
        p1.addProperty( denotedBy, pe1 );

        // for illustration, we just print the contents of the model now
        m.write( System.out, "Turtle" );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new ProcessTest().run();
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sio:     <http://semanticscience.org/resource/> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

sio:processEffect1
      a       sio:ProcessEffect .

sio:process1
      a       sio:Process ;
      sio:denotedBy sio:processEffect1 .
```